# Bootstrap 4 border in row

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4, row, overflow

I have this code, with border bottom in every row.

https://jsfiddle.net/brygom/0z582swx/3/
For some reason the border bottom of row not complete all row width. Even if i don't use `overflow-auto` the border not completed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are forcing to use 13 .col-2 inside a unique row. In Bootstrap this is not possible because a row has a maximum size of 12, so if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4, if instead you want two equal-width columns across you can use .col-6. [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) you can se in detail how the bootstrap grid system works.

If you try to substitute .col-6 to .col-1 infact, you can see that the width of the line increases. The problem is that you have 13 columns and so I think that using the Bootstrap grid system is not the better choice.

If you want to create a table I suggest you to use the Bootstrap table, in this way you can add as many columns as you want with your preferred customized style. ([here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/) you can find the documentation).

If you want to customize better the table you can use instead a normal `<table>`.